Error: Unknown property 'showConfirmationPopup'in visualforce component
Controller:
public Boolean showConfirmationPopup { get; set; }
// Initialize popup properties
this.showConfirmationPopup = false;

<apex:component id="cComponent" layout="none" allowDML="true"><!-- 
<apex:attribute name="cCtrl" type="EUIController" required="true" />
<apex:attribute name="opp" type="Opportunity" required="true" description="Opportunity" />
<apex:attribute name="readOnlyMode" type="Boolean" required="true" description="make the component read only" />
<apex:attribute type="boolean" name="renderInUI" default="false"  />

<apex:outputPanel id="popupPanel" styleClass="popup" layout="block" rendered="{!showConfirmationPopup}">
    <div class="popupBackground">
        <div class="popupContent">
            <apex:outputText value="{!confirmationMessage}" />
            <br/><br/>
            <!-- Yes button -->
            <apex:commandButton value="Yes" action="{!handleYes}" reRender="popupPanel, someOtherComponent" />
            <!-- No button -->
            <apex:commandButton value="No" action="{!handleNo}" reRender="popupPanel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:outputPanel>

I would appreciate your help. How can I resolve this problem?

You're not specifying a controller for your Visualforce component, so the markup can't know how to reference showConfirmationPopup .
You need to add the controller to your <apex:component declaration.
e.g.
<apex:component id="cComponent" layout="none" allowDML="true" controller="MyVisualforceController">

